# Plugin compatibility with HPOS - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

As the woocoommerce is rolling out it's new update named High Performance Order Storage (HPOS). I had developed a woocommerce extension earlier which uses the code below.

```
   $args = array(
            'customer' => $company_users,
            'page'     => $current_page,
            'paginate' => true,
        );
    if ( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'wcb2brp_get_credit_logs' ) ) {
        $args['payment_method'] = 'wcb2brp-credit-payment';
    
    }
    if ( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'wcb2brp_start_date' ) ) {
        $args['date_created'] = '>=' . filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'wcb2brp_start_date' );
    }
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Will this code meet the HPOS requirement which makes my extension compatible with woocommerce.

Also is there any way I can verify if my extensions are compatible with woocommerce or not?

Some of the refrence links I have gone through by woocommerce are:

[HPOS guide by woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/)

[Github Recipe Book](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/High-Performance-Order-Storage-Upgrade-Recipe-Book)